# What is the ALM REST URL for the list of users under a project

Tags: rest, api, alm

I am trying to get the users which are availale for assignment under an ALM project. The same list of users you get when you click the "Assigned to" and "Assigned to (name)" headers in the browser client of ALM.

I have searched around the web trying to find a resource for this, but without luck. I have also tried to guess, e.g. like:

### https://url/qcbin/api/domains/domain/projects/project/users or https://url/qcbin/api/domains/domain/projects/project/accounts etc.

Using ALM 12.21

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the customization command, for instance:

```
Description
The data on the specified project user.

URL
/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/customization/users/{user name}
```

Operation to be performed is a GET in this case. You can refer to the REST API documentation.

This gives you the project users. Hope this clarify your query! Have a nice day.